# How to user embedded Jetty with HTTPS over port other than 443?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jetty, embedded-jetty

I've been serving a web application over HTTPS on the default port of 443 with embedded Jetty (let's call that serverA) on Ubuntu 14.04 (using a self-signed certificate). It's been working fine for ages now, but I want to run another embedded Jetty web server (serverB) on the same machine. I'd like serverB to run SSL using the default port 443, so I need to change serverA to listen for requests on some other port.

I've been trying serverA with 444 and 8080. The server fires up just fine, telling me that it's listening for requests on the correct port. but requests just hang and the server logs are telling me nothing. If I start the server up listening on port 443, then everything works fine.

I didn't think it matters which port I use as long as I have the web server configured to use SSL. Is there something else I need to do?

Here's my launch code:

```
    // Java 7 bug (feature?) - this disables SNI everywhere...
    // required or else outgoing HTTPS requests will fail
    System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

    PropertyConfigurator.configure("./log4j.properties");
    Server server = new Server();

    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setWar("war");
    server.setHandler(webapp);

    HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
    https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("keystore.jks");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("password");

    ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(https));
    sslConnector.setPort(port);

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { sslConnector });

    try {
        LOG.info("Starting server on port " + port);
        server.start();
        server.join();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.fatal("The web server has crashed", e);
    }
```

*Note: The reason this is on StackOverflow and not SuperUser or something else is because, from what I understand, the port used for HTTPS is not important. I'm assuming this is a Jetty issue, then.*

**Edit:**
Sorry, forgot to mention Jetty version. It's **9.2.0**

Comment: As long as you are using a released and stable jetty (not M0, M1, RC0, etc) then you are OK.  Latest mature/stable release is `9.2.3.v20140905`

Comment: As it happens, I am using jetty-all-9.2.0.M0.jar - should I not?

Comment: That's "Milestone 0" a pre-release, considered unstable, only for testers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, as you didn't tell jetty what is considered secure, its just using defaults.

```java
HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
https.setSecurePort(port); /* missing this */
https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
```

This might seem strange, but is actually needed, because you can be considered secure even if the connection arrived in a non-secure way.  Such as from a proxy or an ssl terminated load balancer in front of jetty (the variety of ways is quite stunning)

Comment: is the `sslConnector.setPort(port)` still required?

Comment: Still hangs on port 444 with the statement included in your solution. I tried removing the `sslConnector.setPort(port)` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Your code works fine here (I chose port 12444, just because I wasn't running as root). Try a port above 1024, if it works, then you are either hitting privileged port issues or firewall issues.

Comment: Gah, I know what it is. I'm running on an AWS EC2 instance with inbound IP/port restrictions - thanks!